# How to get the size in bytes of an excel file while writing to it in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel, temporary-files

I have a bit of a problem around here, I just can't get it done.

The thing is that I'm using POI for a project in Java and I have to get the final outputs in .xls format(HSSF for Apache).

So, my business rules state that each file I generate has to be 12 MB as a maximun file size.

But I know .xls has some internal way of dealing the data(XML I guess), so this adds more bytes than just putting the result in a plain text file. I just can't get the size of the Excel Workbook since it generates itself in a temporal location(I can't find it) and I just can't read it while writting.

Is there any way to get the size in bytes of the Excel output file while Java writes to it using the HSSF Workbook Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some research on the API, I found out that the method called getBytes() returns an Array of bytes of every data on the workbook (Sheets, rows, data, etc) so using the lenght would return a **very** close aproximate of the bytes generated by the final workbook used by the user.

Comment: That's quite an expensive call to make, so be aware of the performance impact of calling it too often!

Comment: Well, I call it in a progresive percentage 10% 30% 50% 70% 90% 95% 97% 98% 99% and each time the loop hits 5000 rows. Performance it's quite well taken. Thanks 4 your concern =D

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to periodically write the file out, and see how big it is. The only way to know for sure how big the file will be is to write it out...

With HSSF, not all cells take up the same amount of size. String cells take up a different size to numeric cells, formula cells vary depending on the number of operators and values in them, string cells vary based on if they're using the same text as a previous cell or not etc. You can do some rough guesses based on the kinds of things you're adding (remembering to take account of cell styles, named ranges, pictures etc), but the only way to be sure is to write it out every so often and see how big it is.

For XSSF, it's even more complicated. Not only do different cells take up different amounts of characters in the XML (much as for HSSF), the .xlsx file format is a compressed format. So, writing the same snippet of XML can take variable amounts of space in the output file, based on how the compression algorithms manage it. (The first one will take more than subsequent ones for example). So, there's even less hope for being certain without saving and testing. Again, you can probably come up with some rough guesses, but the only way to be sure is to save and see.

If you want a predictable file size, you'll have to use something purely text based, eg a .CSV file.

Comment: I wish my boss could understand that (sigh). Anyway, while doing some research I found this: http://bug.javlin.eu/browse/CL-2094 it looks like it's hardcoded to be generated in the temporal folder defined by the OS, hence the same one used by java. I just can't find that temporal file, working with Microsoft software it's just pure hell on earth.

Comment: That's talking about the uncompressed files, so you can't use that as you don't know how much they'll shrink when they get zipped into the final .xlsx structure. I'd suggest you take a best guess on the number of rows/cells you can fit in, knock off 25%, and normally spit out 8mb files but the odd one a bit bigger...

Comment: Thanks a lot Gagravarr for your time, but I found an easier approach that is less complex.